# error conflicting data types

Tags: c, types

```
int main() {
long int a;
long int b;
long int c;
long int d;
long int e;
scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
int i,j;
long int sum = 0;
long int largestsum =0;
long int smallestsum = 0 ;
long int  a [5] = {a,b,c,d,e};
for ( i =0;i<5;i++){
    for (j = 0;j<5;j++){
        if (a[j]!=a[i]){
            sum+=a[j];

        }
    }
    if (largestsum <sum){
        largestsum = sum;
    }
    if (smallestsum>sum){
        smallestsum = sum;
    }
}
printf("%ld %ld",largestsum,smallestsum);
return 0;
```

}

i'm trying to find the largest and the smallest sums between 5 inputs the problem is that i made the array of long ints the same as variables and i have the error conflicting data types in a which is the array what is the problem ?

Comment: Maybe use a bit more descriptive variable names?

Comment: `%lld` is `long long`. `%ld` is `long`. What is *largest sum*? Do you mean the *largest sum contiguous subarray*?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.  there are several reasons, including the necessary `#include` statements are missing

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful. (and fix the format specifiers to match the parameters)  I.E. `if( 5 != scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld %ld",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e) ) { // handle error event }`

Comment: the posted code declares `a` as a `long int`.  Shortly later the posted code declares `a` as an array. Which results in the compiler raising an `error` message.  Why are you posting code that does not cleanly compile?  Your question is about a run time problem, not about a compile problem, so you did not post the code that shows the problem.  Do you expect us to 'read your mind' as to what your actual code looks like?

Comment: the posted code contains the 'magic' number 5.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give the 'magic' number a meaningful name and they use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: inserting appropriate horizontal spacing (inside parens, after a comma, between elements of a `for()` statement, etc) makes the code much easier for humans to read. (the compiler doesn't care)

Comment: regarding the code block beginning with: `if (smallestsum>sum)`  the variable `smallestsum` is initialized to 0 so this code block is never entered

Comment: when the values read are 1,2,3,4,5  then the 'largestsum` cannot possibly be greater than 15, but the code logic outputs 60!  So the logic is not correct

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) variable names should indicate usage or content (or better, both). 2) consistently indent the code. Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'. unindent before EVERY closing brace '}'. Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level. 3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: @user3629249 I think the question is in fact about the compiler error (not about a runtime problem), though the only indicator is the title. I assume OP is not actually aware of the problems beyond compiling. By the way, I spotted your comment after answering. I acknowledge that it basically contains the answer for (what I believe to be) the question.

Comment: The code seems to try to do 5 sums. Each is summing all of the values in the array, except one. The biggest sums will be the one missing the smallest value, the smallest sum will be the one missing the highest value?

Comment: The fact that the largest sum is much too high is probably because the "sum" is not reset. It is only initialised, outside the outer loop. Try resetting it at the start of the outer loop.

Comment: Best practice: When collecting "smallest" init with highest possible value (quite high for the sum of 5 free integers). When searching "largest", init with lowest possible value (very negative for the sum of 5 free unsigned integers). Otherwise you would have to somehow keep track of whether you have already found something. Alternatively, init both to the first sum. But I do not like that very much. I like the "setup" to be clean before the input data arrive.

Comment: I wonder about `if (a[j]!=a[i])`. If I am at least close to understanding what the code is supposed to do, I think it should be `if (j!=i)`. Otherwise you hidden-hardcode the assumption that 5 different values are entered. Try entering 5 identical numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What is `a` ?
Is it a long int as in line 2 ? `long int a;`
Or is it an array of long int as in line 12 `long int  a [5] = {a,b,c,d,e};`

The compiler gets confused when he sees line 12, assumes you are doing the same thing again (which it would probably tolerate), then sees that you are using a different type (array instead of long int).
He concludes "Those are not the same types. That is a conflict of types."

Solution:
Rename a-the-array to "liArray", everywhere it is referenced.
Et voila: `gcc -Wall Toy.c` does not complain and running it does not crash.

Afterwards read the comments, they have more to say on how to get the program actually do what it is supposed to. Below I did only the array renaming.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    long int a;  
    long int b;  
    long int c;  
    long int d;  
    long int e;  
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld %ld",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);  
    int i,j;  
    long int sum = 0;  
    long int largestsum =0;  
    long int smallestsum = 0 ;  
    long int  liArray[5] = {a,b,c,d,e};  
    for ( i =0;i<5;i++){  
        for (j = 0;j<5;j++){  
            if (liArray[j]!=liArray[i]){  
                sum+=liArray[j];         
            }  
        }  
        if (largestsum <sum){  
            largestsum = sum;  
        }  
        if (smallestsum>sum){  
            smallestsum = sum;  
        }  
    }  
    printf("%ld %ld",largestsum,smallestsum);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I also changed `%lld` ->`%ld`, but that is not related to the question.

Comment: thank you guys so much it was stupid mistake i'm sorry :D